# How can I prepend a string to list of elements in Scala?

Tags: scala, list

I have the following requirement:

`val lst = List("a","b","c")`

I would like to prepend with the text `test` to all the elements in the list. The output should be like as below:

```
testa
testb
testc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val alteredList = lst.map(item => "test" + item)
```

Comment: or even ```lst.map("test" +)```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more options:

If you want a new `List` with the elements as you said:

```
val newList = lst.map("test".concat(_))
```

If you just want to print them, then you can do something like this:

```
lst.foreach(item => println(s"test$item"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create list with such elements you could write:

`val result = list.map("test" + _)`

After that of course you could print them all:

`result foreach println`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that output you can write:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val lst = List("a","b","c")
  lst.map(s => "test" + s).foreach(println)
}
```